# similar to seaborn's hue function in plotly?

Tags: python, time-series, plotly

[image]

```
geo1 = go.Scatter(
x=geo['Year'],
y=geo['Number'],
mode='lines',
marker=dict(color=geo['Geographical region'],size=4, showscale=False),
name='geo',
showlegend=True)


data = [geo1]

layout = dict(
title='Working VISA in UK by Regions',
xaxis=dict(title='Year'),
yaxis=dict(title='Number'), showlegend=True)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

The result shows:
[image]

what I want is to use a similar function as 'hue' in seaborn:
[image]

how to do the plotly coding by regions in different colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
traces=[]

for x, geo_region in geo.groupby('Geographical region'):

traces.append(go.Scatter(x=geo_region.Dates, y=geo_region.Number, name=x, mode='lines'))

fig = go.Figure(data=traces)
iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using pandas, I recommend to use Plotly Express. In this case the code is very simple and intuitive:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(geo, x="Year", y="Number", color="Geographical region",
              line_group="Geographical region")
fig.show()
```

---

Or, from version 4.8, you can even replace the default plotting backend of pandas simply by writing:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly" # just once at the beginning

geo.plot.line(x="Year", y="Number", color="Geographical region",
              line_group="Geographical region")
```

Reference: https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/