# Seaborn HUE in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I have this dataframe [Gas Price Brazil](https://www.kaggle.com/matheusfreitag/gas-prices-in-brazil)  / 
[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwSSR.png)
I get only the gasoline values from this DF and want to plot the average price (PREÇO MEDIO) over time (YEARS - ANO) from each region (REGIAO)

I used Seaborn with HUE and get this:

[image: Seaborn Plot]

But when I try to plot the same thing at Plotly the result is:

[image: Plotly Plot]

How can I get the same plot with plotly?

I searched and find this: [Seaborn Hue on Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047884/similar-to-seaborns-hue-function-in-plotly)

But this didn't work to me.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Your question is interesting, but you should have a look on 

[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to increase your chances of receiving useful answers. In particular, you should consider this:

1. screenshots of plots should be included in the question itself and not links.
2. Data samples should be provided as links to csv files or as small samples in the question itself. Never as screenshots.
3. All necessary code to reproduce your attempts should be included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer:**

You will achieve the same thing using plotly express and the `color` attribute:

```
fig = px.line(dfm, x="dates", y="value", color='variable')
```

**The details:**

You haven't described the structure of your data in detail, but assigning hue like this is normally meant to be applied to a data structure such as...

```
Date    Variable    Value
01.01.2020    A    100
01.01.2020    B    90
01.02.2020    A    110
01.02.2020    B    120
```

... where a unique hue or color is assigned to different variable names that are associated with a timestamp column where each timestamp occurs as many times as there are variables.

And that seems to be the case for [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) too:

> hue : name of variables in data or vector data, optional
>
> Grouping variable that will produce points with different colors. Can
>   be either categorical or numeric, although color mapping will behave
>   differently in latter case.

You can achieve the same thing with plotly using the `color` attribute in `go.Scatter()`, but it seems that you could make good use of `plotly.express` too. Until you've provided a proper data sample, I'll show you how to do it using some sampled data in a dataframe using [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# sample time series data
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10,12,size=(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=50).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0]=0
df=df.cumsum().reset_index()

# melt data to provide the data structure mentioned earlier
dfm=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['dates'], value_vars=df.columns[1:])
dfm.set_index('dates')
dfm.head()

# plotly
fig = px.line(dfm, x="dates", y="value", color='variable')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, simple and quick solution.

Comment: Sure, sorry for not having checked before, I'm still learning the forum features and how to behave :D

Comment: @vinicvaz No problem! I think the most important thing is to ask a question, get an answer and give feedback. Som consider the voting system to be more than enough feedback. Personally I try to make sure to not leave a down-vote without a comment as to *why*. But I rarely leave down-votes. If the question is useful, and the answers contribute to a solution, then I always leave an up-vote. By now you have earned the right to up-vote posts yourself. Giving 600 votes even earns you a reward.